# MongoDb and Linq

Tags: mongodb

I am a little confused with the Mongodb offical support of Linq. Does it officially support it? I relaize there is NoRM out there but it seems like that it uses an outdated driver and project is abandon. Is this correct? What is current status of Linq support for Mongodb and what its performance like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I know, the official MongoDB C# driver is currently having LINQ capability added to it.  There have been several LINQ related additions made at the driver's [GitHub site](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver) in the last few weeks. You can also see the change log and planning for the driver at it's [Jira site](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP). It hasn't been "released" yet, but you can take it out for a spin by getting the latest code from GitHub.

Up to now, I have had a good experience (performance and functionality-wise) using another open-source library called FluentMongo.  [See it's GitHub site.](https://github.com/craiggwilson/fluent-mongo) It is a LINQ extension library built to sit on top of the official C# driver. It is maintained by Craig Wilson, who is also involved in the official C# driver development. It is actively maintained and I know Craig has been giving feedback to the LINQ implementation in the official driver.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The C# driver will officially support LINQ in the next release (1.4).

Answer (score 0):

yes the c# driver supports linq in most scenarios as of april 2019.

i'm using a [MongoDAL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDAL/) to make life easier.

check the readme file to get things going quickly.